Order of the images of Dehn twists in the quantum representation of Reshetikhin-Turaev TQFT and relation to Vafa's theorem
Short version
Let $\mathcal T$ be the modular functor of a Reshetikhin-Turaev TQFT defined over a modular (semisimple) category $\mathcal C$ and a ring $K$, and $\Sigma$ be some compact (closed) surface. If $\phi$ is a Dehn twist about a simple closed curve on $\Sigma$, the TQFT will induce a (projective) $K$-linear morphism $\mathcal T(\Sigma)\to \mathcal T(\Sigma)$. My question is: is there any relation between the twist, $\theta$, of $\mathcal C$ and the image $\mathcal T(\phi)$?
Long version
I am trying to understand the statement, which I found a few times in the literature, that Dehn twists have finite order in the induced representation of the TQFT (in fact, as some Freedman et al. point out, this seems to be the easiest argument for the lack of faithfulness of the representations induced by TQFTs). In particular, I found this quote from Müller and Woike:

The most classical
construction for modular functors uses as an input datum a modular fusion category, a linear
abelian monoidal category with a non-degenerate braiding (only finite direct sums of the unit trivially double braid with all objects) and a ribbon structure, subject to the assumption of finiteness
(the category is linearly equivalent to finite-dimensional modules over some algebra) and, most
importantly, semisimplicity. In that situation, one does not only obtain a modular functor, but a
three-dimensional topological field theory via the Reshetikhin-Turaev construction [RT90, RT91].
For this construction, the Dehn twists act always by automorphisms of finite order by Vafa’s Theorem [...]

Vafa's theorem implies that, if $\mathcal V$ is a (semisimple) modular category of twist $\theta$, then $\theta$ has finite order. It seems to me that for this relation of the finite order of the Dehn twists and Vafa's theorem to make sense, the Dehn twits need to be somehow mapped to twists (or sum/product of twists?) of the modular category by the Reshetikhin-Turaev TQFT. However, I do not understand why this should be the case. In fact, in Turaev's book (Quantum Invariants of Knots and 3-Manifolds), the twists of the auxiliary ribbon (in this case, modular category) are defined through Dehn twists (page 258), but I do not see why this would necessarily imply any relation between $\mathcal T(\phi)$ and $\theta_{\mathcal{T}(\Sigma)}$ for a surface $\Sigma$. Is my interpretation of the quote correct? Is there a more direct construction that makes this clear? And if so, does such a construction hold for all Dehn twists on the surface $\Sigma$ (in particular, does it give that all Dehn twists of $\Sigma$ will be mapped to finite order elements by the representation?)

Here's the shortest answer I can think of: Suppose $\gamma$ is any simple closed curve and we want to show its Dehn twist $T_\gamma$ has finite image in the RT representation.
Case 1:
Since any two non-separating curves are connected by a mapping class, there exists some $f\in \operatorname{Mod}(\Sigma)$ such that $f(\gamma) = \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is any "good" non-separating curve, eg. any of the non-separating Lickorish generators. For instance, take $\alpha$ to be a meridian.  Moreover, since Dehn twists satisfy: $T_{f(\gamma) = \alpha} = f\circ T_\gamma \circ f^{-1}$, we know that $T_\alpha$ has finite image iff $T_\gamma$ has finite image.
Case 2:
If $\gamma$ is separating it can mapped to one of the separating curve Lickorish generators.
In particular, we have reduced the problem to that of the specific Lickorish generators, for which you can now use Vafa's theorem.

I see! This makes sense, I actually talked to some people about this problem the last couple of months and this is something that people mentioned. Thanks a lot, very helpful picture!
